# Converting numbers stored without decimals to include decimals

Tags: sql, decimal

I have a number stored in a SQL database.

The numbers are stored like 1000000, 161000, and 93700. The first one actually represents 100% and the second one represents 16.7% and the last one 9.37%.

I need to compare them to another column in the DB that is stored as a decimal. I split the first column using left and right and then concatenated and added a decimal. Then I cast as a type decimal.

Is there any easier way of doing this?

Comment: Could you include an example of the result you obtain after you _"split the first column using left and right and then concatenated and added a decimal"_?

Comment: Are the integers stored as numbers or strings?

Comment: You should include the query (or the code) you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select number / 10000.0
```